# How to specifically splice out an item from a user made array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, array-splice

I'm attempting to add/remove specific items from my array using only one button.
So far, when i click the button it will push the item into the array, if i click again it will remove the item from the array.
My problem is if i have more buttons which add a different item to my array each time, clicking any of the buttons again will completely empty the array.

I know its my splice, and it might just because its 1 AM, but i'll be damned if i can understand what i am doing wrong. if anyone could show me the correct way to do this that would be awesome.
Here's my sample code,

```
    var libary =  Array();

    Array.prototype.contains = function ( needle ) {
       for (i in this) {
           if (this[i] == needle) return true;
       }
       return false;
    }

    function btn1() {
        if (libary.contains("Big Book")){
        libary.splice("Big Book");
        document.getElementById("1").style.cssText = "border: 0;border-radius:0;border-color:0;box-shadow:0;}";
        }else{
        libary.push("Big Book");
        document.getElementById("1").style.cssText = "border: 5px solid #4099FF;border-radius: 12px;outline: none;border-color: #4099FF;box-shadow: 0 0 15px #4099FF;}";
        }
    };
   function btn2() {
    if (libary.contains("Small Book")){
    libary.splice("Small Book");
    document.getElementById("2").style.cssText = "border: 0;border-radius:0;border-color:0;box-shadow:0;}";
    }else{
    libary.push("Small Book");
  document.getElementById("2").style.cssText = "border: 5px solid #4099FF;border-radius: 12px;outline: none;border-color: #4099FF;box-shadow: 0 0 15px #4099FF;}";
  }
};
```

Bare in mind this is just a sample, and there are roughly 20 more buttons.

Comment: Right, you are not using `.splice` correctly. Have a look at the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) first. For example, the first argument passed to `.splice` needs to be a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp) the `splice()` method takes 2 required parameters in order to remove an element, "index" where to start from and "number" of items to be removed.
You can try calling the `splice()` method like this

```
...
var index = library.indexOf("Big Book");
libary.splice(index, 1);
...
```

This way you are removing just one element at a specified index.

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lgr5m9yz/2/) code that runs as you want it to, it also logs the array to the console on every click so you could see the results.

Comment: `function btn1() {
        if (libary.contains("Big Book")){
        var index = library.indexOf("Big Book");
        libary.splice(index, 1);
        document.getElementById("1").style.cssText = "border: 0;border-radius:0;border-color:0;box-shadow:0;}";
        }else{
        libary.push("Big Book");
        document.getElementById("1").style.cssText = "border: 5px solid #4099FF;border-radius: 12px;outline: none;border-color: #4099FF;box-shadow: 0 0 15px #4099FF;}";
        }`    I'm not quite sure how to fit that into my if statement, and while it works, it stills empties the entire array.

Comment: Can you provide a sample JSFiddle code so i could poke it around a bit, and attempt to debug it.

Comment: I actually tried it this way earlier and was not sure about actually getting it to fit within my function , then i thought splice would the same way as push would, alas. it does not,

Comment: sure mate, gimmie a few

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lgr5m9yz/ I'll be damned if i can get the actual fiddle to work, since it calls all my functions uncaught reference errors. But there it is, it should work.

Comment: Ok, i got your code workin, im updating my answer with working code on JSFiddle.. Te reason your fiddle was not working is because you had to have your js code inside the html body in order for onclick to trigger it.

Comment: DING DING MATE works like a charm! ,as a novice i look up to programming wizards such as yourself. You earned that answer.  EDIT, thanks for also going through the steps and telling me exactly what i did wrong.